# Sending ether from transaction to contract in Pyethereum using Solidity

Tags: solidity, pyethereum

I want to transfer some ethers from a user account to a contract account in Solidity. I tried using the following syntax:

```
contract_code = """ 
contract bug {
    function load_money() returns (uint32) {

       if(msg.value != 10) {
          return(0);
       }
    }
}
"""

# Create the contract
contract = s.abi_contract(contract_code, language='solidity')

# Transfer money
contract.load_money(value=5, sender=tester.k0)
```

I get a transaction failure when I try this. Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give us more details, like dumping the contract object and the error message?